# Help defining an equation for a problem

Tags: calculus, functions

So I have this question: A square is to be cut from each corner of a piece of paper which is 10
inches by 14 inches and the sides are to be folded up to create an open
box. If one wants to maximize the volume of the box, what should
be the side-length of the squares being cut?

I understand that I should use calculus to find the critical points and determine the maximum volume, but I can't figure the function to state. I am having trouble conceptualizing the problem. Could someone help?

Thank you!

Comment: If $x$ is the side-length of the piece being cut out, then the original piece of paper side length is reduced by ? and the function describing the area of the base in terms of $x$ is ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \; \bf{cm}.$ be removed from each corner of Rectangular base, Then $\bf{Length} = (14-2x)$

and $$\bf{Breadth} = (10-2x)$$ and $\bf{Height} = x$

Now $$\bf{Volume(V)} = (14-2x)\cdot (10-2x)\cdot x$$

Now $\bf{Maximize}$ The expression.

So $$\displaystyle V (x)=4\cdot (x-7)\cdot (x-5)\cdot x = 4\cdot \left(x^3-12x^2+35x\right) $$

So $$V'(x) = 4\left[3x^2-24x+35\right]$$

Now For Max. and Min. , Put $$V'(x) = 0\Rightarrow (3x^2-24x+35) =0\displaystyle \Rightarrow x= 4\pm \sqrt{\frac{13}{3}}$$

Now Use Second Derivative Test

$$V''(x) = 4\left[6x-24\right]$$ and Put value of $x$ for which $V'(x) = 0$

If $V''(x)>0\;,$ Then Point of Minimuim and If $V''(x)<0\;,$ Then Point of Maximum .

Comment: Thanks! I just couldn't see the picture.

Comment: I have another one: A rectangular area of 800 square feet is to be enclosed by a fence and
then divided down the middle by another piece of fence. The fence
down the middle costs $2.00 per foot, while the fence on the perimeter
costs $2.00 per yard. Find the minimum possible cost for the fence.
In this one, I can't figure out how I could know the length of the fence in the middle ?